# What are the names of adityas and saptarshi?

Tags: gods, saptarshi

Please tell the names of adityas and saptarishi for the present Manvantara i.e., Vaivasvata Manvantara.

Comment: you should edit this post as what you are asking is not making any sense and it will invite lot of downvote and clear candidate of being closed in its current state

Comment: Tell names of 12 demigods,seven rishis,8vasus.

Comment: There are always different saptarishis (seven rishi) on different [manvantara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manvantara#Sub-divisions). Here are the [list of all saptarishis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi#Names_Of_The_Sapta_Rishis) of all manvatars.

Comment: And here are the [details and names of demigods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demigod#Hinduism). And here is the [list of 8 vasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasu#Eight_Vasus).

Comment: You should edit your question and ask tha name of 12 adityas and 7 saptarishish

Answer (score 4):

#### The Saptarshis of the Vaivasvata Manvantara (According to Brahma Purana) are"

(From Chapter 3, Manvantaras)

1. Atri
2. Vaśiṣṭa
3. Kaśyapa
4. Gautama
5. Bharadvāja
6. Viśvāmitra
7. Jamadagni

#### There are 12 Ādityas ruling for 12 months.

1. Dhātā - Caitra
2. Aryamā - Vaiśākha
3. Mitra - Jyaiṣṭha
4. Varuṇa   - Āṣāḍha
5. Indra    - Śrāvaṇa
6. Vivasvān - Bhādra
7. Pūṣā - Māgha
8. Parjanya - Phālguna
9. Aṁśu - Mārgaśīrṣa
10. Bhaga - Puṣya
11. Tvaṣṭā - Āśvina
12. Viṣṇu  - Kārttika

> Thus, throughout the twelve months, the lord of the sun travels in all directions with his six types of associates, disseminating among the inhabitants of this universe purity of consciousness for both this life and the next.  [[12.11.46]](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/11/46)

Refer Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam [Canto 12 Chapter 11 shlokas 33 to  for more information](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/11)